# Show all posts of sub category in a page like: foo.com/category/subcategory/ using UNCODE Theme

Tags: categories

I'll be upfront and say that this is a difficult question to phrase for achieving the "correct" answer as it seems it can be done a few ways.

I am using the WP Theme Uncode from undsgn.com that uses the WP Bakery Page Builder / Visual Composer. Here is a brief how-to video that shows the module as part of the theme to query each archive type.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8_H2neBRRA

I want to create categories and subcategories within the Posts section to differentiate the posts:
https://toddsines.com/direction/ <-- lists all Direction spots
[image: direction]
https://toddsines.com/direction/mv/ <-- *Should* list all Music Videos I directed, but instead throws a 404 error.  
[image: direction/fashionfilms]
I tried looking into tweaking the Uncode child theme *functions.php, category.php, archive.php* and *category-$slug.php*, as well as some specific subcategory PHP files to show just the results of 1 Subcategory instead of the Parent category to no avail.
[Page template in two level deep folder](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/249984/page-template-in-two-level-deep-folder/346428#346428)

I tried to follow this and it is **way** over my head [I'm a director/photographer/musician, not really a developer, but will get my hands dirty when necessary]
[How to create a category and sub-category sorted blogroll with all posts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99492/how-to-create-a-category-and-sub-category-sorted-blogroll-with-all-posts?rq=1)

Additionally, I saw that the developer in the StackExchange link tried to automatically create archives of categories without having to hard-code each and every subcategory, because they may expand, shrink, renamed or  reorganized. So making custom content blocks, then making custom pages to display that custom content block within the Uncode theme's post/page builder seems redundant given that the work is being categorized in the post as each post is made.

I am surprised that this functionality is not standard practice. I tried looking for plugins and I clearly cannot find the right flavor of queries or something that does not break the Uncode theme to achieve my desires. I would prefer an elegant example — don't we all?

1. I *DO NOT* want a text list.
2. I want it to look exactly like the examples above and in the YouTube clip — aka styled buttons with animations, CSS-styled text overtop regenerated thumbnails from the media library, etc.
3. I have fought with WP for the last 4 days trying to figure this out :(

My only option to achieve the thumbnail display as shown, is to create Query-based content blocks for each division [subcategory] of work, such as Commercials, in a parent category, such as Direction.

1. Create the query content block showing just Commercials
2. Create page to show that content block
3. Add link in menu to link to the page to show Commercials

It would ideal to make a subcategory page template that automatically creates a nice looking index with the work in each subcategory without me having to do independent queries of everything.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Todd

Comment: Hi sines, welcome to [wordpress.se]. While the community as a whole considers third-party themes to be off-topic I kinda like this question and hope you get a good answer. If you get down-votes I just wanted you to know why.